# Running an underpowered test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-power

Perhaps someone could help me with an issue.

I have a new product that some users might be interested in, and would like to email them an offer seeing if they sign up for it.

The problem is that some groups barely have any signups to the service (CR < 0.01%) and it is not realistic to run the test in a timeframe that will allow for enough traffic to gain a statistically significant audience.

What would be the best course of action to proceed with testing on something like this?

Comment: It is not so much the _percentage_ of users that matters as the _number_ of user that do. // There is nothing illegal about running an underpowered test. The risk is that you might not detect a real difference. [And for a group of users with very low traffic, it might not matter much to the bottom line if their opinion isn't crystal clear.]

Answer (score 0):

As Bruce pointed out, running the tests without sufficient power increases type II errors (false negatives) but it also increases type I errors (false positives).

To avoid this you could only run the tests on the groups that are large enough to give you sufficient power for your statistical tests. Alternatively, you could perhaps bin some of the small groups together so that you have larger groups that give you sufficient power. Other than that, I think I'd need to know more about your problem to be able to suggest any thing else.